# Hibernate select elements of collection with a given property

Tags: hibernate, hql

Entity `Project` has a collection property `contributors` mapped with a `@OneToMany` relationship to entity `User`

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "projects" )
public class Project {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "project_contributors")
    private List<User> contributors = new ArrayList<User>();

    ...
}
```

I then need to check if `contributors` already has a `user` with `id` `contributorId` before adding it. I am trying with HQL query, but I am clearly quite innept.

What I am trying:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
        "select p.contributors from Project p where p.id = :pId and p.contributors.id = :cId"
    );

query.setParameter("pId", projectId);
query.setParameter("cId", contributorId);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<User> res = (List<User>) query.list();
```

But it gives the error

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [project0_.id.contributors] with element property reference [id]
```

Is there a good samaritan that would like to give me a little push?

another try I made is

```
"select p.contributors as c from Project p where p.id = :pId and c.id = :cId"
```

but nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`contributors` is a Collection. As such, it does not have an attribute named id.

Id is an attribute of the elements of this Collection.

You can fix the issue by joining the collection instead of dereferencing it:

```
SELECT p 
  FROM Project pj 
  JOIN pj.contributors  p 
 WHERE pj.id       = :pId
   AND p.Id     = :cId
```

Comment: Tanvi you are awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It helps to read your HQL as if it was Java code trying to dereference fields in Java classes:

```
p.contributors.id
```

You're trying to access the `id` of `p.contributors`, which is a `List<User>`. A List doesn't have an ID. So that can't work.

```
select p.contributors
```

Such a query, if it were correct, would return a list of list of contributors. That's not what you want either.

How would you do it in SQL? With a join. Same with JPQL:

```
select c from Project p
join p.contributors c
where p.id = :pId and c.id = :cId
```

Doing a join and assigning it an alias allows querying the target entity of the association.

Comment: thanks, I have given the answer to @Tanvi, I hope that's ok. Is there a way to make this same query with Hibernate Criteria?