# In Java getting concurrentModification while parsing nested objects before persisting

Tags: java

In a Spring boot app with Spring data jpa, I'm getting an object that represents entities in database, with several levels of associations parent -> child with arrayLists. I have to make some check on some properties for database integrity purpose,
and i need to map the association if the result is ok. But i can't do that without getting a ConcurrentModificationException, cause i am modifying the objects while iterating.

Here is the object i get:

```
{
  "name": "menu test",
  "description": "description test for menu",
  "price": 15,
  "menuCourses": [
    {
      "category": "Entrée",
      "productsInCourse": [
        {
          "product": {
            "id": 1
          },
          "extraCost": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Plat",
      "productsInCourse": [
        {
          "product": {
            "id": 4
          },
          "extraCost": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are my entities concerned (I omitted getters setters and constructors):

```java
@Entity
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Double price;
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "menu",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MenuCourse> menuCourses = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public void addCourse(MenuCourse course) {
        this.menuCourses.add(course);
        course.setMenu(this);
    }

@Entity
public class MenuCourse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "menuCourse",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ProductInCourse> productsInCourse = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Category category;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Menu menu;

    public void addProductInMenu(ProductInCourse productInCourse) {
        this.productsInCourse.add(productInCourse);
        productInCourse.setMenuCourse(this);
    }

@Entity
public class ProductInCourse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Double extraCost;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Product product;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MenuCourse menuCourse;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<ProductInCourse> productsInMenu = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Category category;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Restaurant restaurant;
```

And my business layer that checks the object before persisting,

```java
 public Menu saveMenu(Long restaurantId, Menu menu) {
        if(this.restaurantRepository.findById(restaurantId).isPresent()) {
            menu.setRestaurant(Restaurant.builder().id(restaurantId).build());

            menu.getMenuCourses().forEach(menuCourse -> {
                if (this.categoryRepository.findCategoryByName(menuCourse.getCategory().getName()).isPresent()) {
                    menu.addCourse(menuCourse); <-- List modification is here

                    menuCourse.getProductsInCourse().forEach(productInCourse -> {
                        if (this.productRepository.findProductByIdAndRestaurantId(
                                productInCourse.getProduct().getId(),
                                restaurantId)
                                .isPresent()) {
                            menuCourse.addProductInMenu(productInCourse); <-- List modification is here
                        } else {
                            throw new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Product '" + productInCourse.getProduct().getId() + "'");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    throw new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Category '" + menuCourse.getCategory().getName() + "'");
                }
            });
            menuRepository.save(menu);
        } else {
            throw new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Restaurant '" + restaurantId + "'");
        }
        return menu;
```

My problem is that i have nested loops, and i don't know how to make an elegant solution to make these checks. I tried with streams, but i didn't manage to do anything close to working.
Thanks for help !

Comment: Did you try using an iterator? `menu.getMenuCourses().iterator(); while(iterator.hasNext()) { MenuCourse course = iterator.next(); if (...) { menu.addCourse(course) } }`

Comment: Also, when working with lists, it could be better to use JPQL or HQL over Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't made a full solution with iterators, cause i wanted to avoid it if i could. But if i have no choice i will. Can you be a little more explicit with your second comment please ? I don't know this way of doing with JPQL or HQL i am using Spring Data Jpa, so the database access is very encapsulated !

Comment: They are query languages (like SQL) but transparent to the underlying RDBMS.  As an example, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37736679/2534090

Comment: Ok i think we misunderstoood each others, i am probably not clear. My query is already handle by JPQL or HQL, throught Spring Data Jpa. The problem is not to persist the objetc, the problem is to build the associations between parent/child entities without having to createthree different iterators and inner for each loops.

Comment: I think you've already defined the *entity associations* as annotations, so you would be looking for inserting some records if a certain criteria is met. In this case, you need to come up with a SQL query on how you would achieve this without Java. When that is done, that your HQL query will also be ready.

Comment: Yes you are right about the annotations, but if i persist the parent entity 'menu', the foreign key is not set automatically and not persisted in the child entities, that's why i am using utility methods menu.addCourse() and menuCourse.addProduct() that will associate objects to each others. That's what it's recommend to do by ThoughtsOnJava or Vlad Mihalcea. And it's these methods call which create the ConcurrentModificationProblem.

Comment: I think, you are basically selecting menu courses whose categories are there in the Category table. In this case, you will be getting a `List<MenuCourse>` each of which you add them to the menu. 

How about writing a HQL query for *selecting* data and using the methods (`addCourse()`) for doing the insertion?

Comment: That sounds interesting ! Though i have no idea how to do it ! I will make some research. Feel free to send me some link if you have an example ! Thanks a lot

Comment: The same example, sent to you above. When you do `query.list()`, you will get the list (here `List<MenuCourse>`) and you can do `menu.add()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i found to parse the nested lists without having a concurrency problem is by using indexes instead of iterator.
I am not very satisified with the solution, i'm pretty sure there is something more elegant to do, but unfortunately i can't figure it out.

```java
    @Override
    public Menu saveMenu(Long restaurantId, Menu menu) {
        Restaurant restaurant = this.restaurantRepository
                .findById(restaurantId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> 
                        new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Restaurant '" + restaurantId + "'")
                );
        log.info("Restaurant id '{}' found", restaurant.getId());
        menu.setRestaurant(restaurant);

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.getMenuCourses().size(); i++) {
            MenuCourse menuCourse = menu.getMenuCourses().get(i);
            String categoryName = menuCourse.getCategory().getName();
            Category category = this.categoryRepository
                    .findCategoryByName(categoryName)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> 
                            new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Category '" + categoryName + "'")
                    );
            log.info("Category name '{}' found", category);
            menuCourse.setMenu(menu);
            menuCourse.setCategory(category);
            menu.getMenuCourses().set(i, menuCourse);

            for (int j = 0; j < menuCourse.getProductsInCourse().size(); j++) {
                ProductInCourse productInCourse = menuCourse.getProductsInCourse().get(j);
                Product product = this.productRepository
                        .findProductByIdAndRestaurantId(
                                productInCourse.getProduct().getId(),
                                restaurantId)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> 
                                new UnknownResourceException("Unknown Product '" + productInCourse.getProduct().getId() + "'")
                        );
                log.info("Product id '{}' for restaurant '{}' found", product.getId(), restaurantId);
                productInCourse.setProduct(product);
                productInCourse.setMenuCourse(menuCourse);
                menuCourse.getProductsInCourse().set(j, productInCourse);
            }
        }
        return menuRepository.save(menu);
    }
```

I'm very interested in better solutions !